# Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'

Tags: mobile, certificate, ios8

I have an application that is ready to use with iOS 8, so we are compiling the app and we are getting this error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'

We deleted the certificates in xcode but it doesn't work, Im not sure what is happening.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now we can not upload ipa's files with Xcode 6, so I just reintalled Xcode 5 and upload the app